# Meteor App: ReferenceError: Package is not defined

Tags: meteor, underscore.js, smooch

I am trying to run an app from [SmoochDesk](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-desk) but I am getting this error. 
[image]

Any advice on where to go from here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by downgrading the meteor to 1.6

> meteor update --release 1.6

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up & sorry for the troubles! I've updated the README instructions to include this 1.6 version requirement.